# unwanted border coming for layout page of struts2 project

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2, tiles

I am devoloping a struts 2 project in which layout page is creating an unwanted border over it. I tried to remove it by putting padding and border as 0 px. but still it is coming.

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>




    <%-- Internal style elements --%>
    <style type="text/css">                                     
    .basestyle {        /*style which is given for the main DIV which includes entire base layout body */

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .headstyle {        /* style which is given for the  DIV which includes header part */
        margin:0px; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #476D9E;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .vericalscroll {        /* style which is given for the  DIV which includes vertical menu part  */
overflow-y:auto;        overflow-x:hidden;
        height:100%;
        width:153px;
        background-color: #476D9E;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-right:1px;
        padding-right:5px;
    }
    .bodystyle {            /* style which is given for the  DIV which includes body part */
        padding: 0px,0px,0px,0px;
        border-bottom:0px;
        border-left:0px;
        border-right:0px;
        border-top:1px #DBDFEC;

        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: lighter;
        height:565px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        width:100%;
        /*text-align: center;*/

    }
    .footstyle {            /* style which is given for the DIV which includes footer part  */

        width: 100%;
        background-color: #476D9E;
        height: 10px;
        bgcolor:#eeeeee;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    }

        </style>
    </head>
        <body   >       

        <div class="basestyle" >

    <div class="headstyle" >
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" /> <%-- including header --%>
    </div>

    <table border="0" width=100% height=87% style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      <tr>

        <td width=153   align="left" valign="top">
        <div class="vericalscroll" >   
                      <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />     <%-- including menu --%>
             </div> </td>





        <td valign="top" align="left" width=88% >
            <div class="bodystyle" align="center" >
                       <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />    <%--  including body  --%>
             </div>    </td>



               </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="footstyle" >                 
                      <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />           <%-- including footer --%>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Red color background is given for identifying body part
[image]

Comment: not sure about tiles, but which theme you arr using?

Comment: even without any themes( just after adding components with blank content itself)it is showing border. In all the layouts which I created it is showing border. Even in downloaded 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove "border-top:1px #DBDFEC" from ".bodystyle" and even instead of all border in your .bodystyle just write border:none;

although i could not see the border in your attached image.

Comment: You can see the red color floating beyond header footer and both the sides

Answer (score 0):

Add this option in the `tile tag` `theme="css_xhtml"`. Then it will be simply treated as HTML tag in view.

Comment: Where in this one?
{
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
}

Comment: No in the tag which is responsible for the border.
May be here <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /> or here <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /> I have never use tiles

Comment: but for getting that image how I created that page is by removing those insert attribute lines. But there also that border was visible.